# Default nice value and priority value of zygote process in android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, init, android-framework

What is the default `nice value` and `priority value` of the zygote process in android?

Can somebody please tell me where is the code to set these parameters?

If zygote forks the child process, will it have the same nice value and priority as of the zygote?